# Spring Security 6 returns error 401 intead of 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

When we are logged in the system and we access a resource that is not mapped ( doesn't exist) we get back a 404 error but it's not happening to me, I'm getting 401 error but it doesnt' make any sense because I'm already logged and i think its a spring security bug.

Filter :

```
if (tokenJWT != null) { 

    User user = recoverUser(tokenJWT); 

    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities()); 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); // The authentication is being done here, the user is already logged!

}

  filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // Here, the request goes to the next class, SecurityConfigurations.
```

}

SecurityConfigurations :

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Primary
public class SecurityConfigurationsImpl {

private final TokenService tokenService;

private final UserRepository userRepository;


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() { 
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationManager 
     authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration 
     authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
   return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws 
  Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", 
            "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2- 
             console/**")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/auth", "/users/register").permitAll() 
            .requestMatchers("/users", "/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .anyRequest().authenticated() 
            .and().cors()
            .and().headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and().csrf().disable()        
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy
            (SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)   
            .sessionCreationPolicy
            .and().addFilterBefore(new 
             AuthenticationJWTFilter(tokenService, userRepository),          
             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new 
             UnauthorizedHandler())
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new 
            ForbiddenHandler());

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new 
    CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", 
    "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

When i'm logged and access any resource that doesn't exist i had do get back 404 error but i'm getting 401.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGBrb.png)

I'm sure the token is valid, the problem just happens when i try to access a resource that doesn't exist!
It started happening when I updated the spring boot version to 3.0.1

I tried to watch videos on  youtube, look for the error solucion on the Google...

Comment: Please share your security config so that people can help better.. migrating to spring 6 has its nuances...

Comment: I just changed it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Spring handles all incoming requests, even if you did not define a specific `@Controller` for it yourself. It tries to handle such an unmapped request as a static resource request, because the default static path pattern includes everything: `/**`. If that fails, it will try to render the error web page (by default `/error`), which falls under your `anyRequest().authenticated()` config and lead to a `401` response. To see the error page, add `/error` to your `permitAll()` config.

Alternatively, if you do not want to make use of the default error page and handle the error yourself, you will need to do the following:

1. Define an exception handler, such as:

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class MyAdvice {

        @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        public MyResponse handleUnknownResource(NoHandlerFoundException e) {
           // handle it
        }
   }
   ```
2. Override the static path pattern, such that it does not handle everything. For example, to only include the `/static` folder, configure `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern: /static`.
3. Now it won't find a handler for your request, but by default it will still redirect you to `/error`, instead of throwing an exception that you can handle yourself. To override that behaviour, configure `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true`

Comment: Work perfectly, ez to understand this case, because Spring secure all path, when you type any path doesn't exist that will match to "/error" but "/error" have been secured, so you need to add "/error" to your permitAll(). hope this help anybody come later.